# strrchr with strtr or str_replace in PHP

Tags: php, str-replace, strtr, strrchr

I have searched a lot of sites and SO answers for replacing characters in strings, but I didn't find a solution.

I need to replace only the last used character 'é' of a string.
It should work for every string, also if the string only contains once character 'é'.

**code**

```
echo strtr (strrchr ( 'accélérer','é' ), array ('é' => 'è'));   //  output èrer
echo str_replace("é","è",strrchr ( 'accélérer','é' ));           // output èrer
```

**desired results**

accélérer -> accél**è**rer

sécher-> s**è**cher

Comment: Hey :) Maybe you want something simpler to use: https://3v4l.org/4anBu . Even works with multiple words, just in case you need it. <- Is that what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have created custom function. Might be useful:

```
<?php
$str = 'accélérer';
$output = replaceMultiByte($str, 'é', 'è');
echo "OUTPUT=".$output; // accélèrer
echo '<br/><br/>';

$str = 'sécher';
$output = replaceMultiByte($str, 'é', 'è');
echo "OUTPUT=".$output; // sècher

function replaceMultiByte($str, $replace, $replaceWith)
{
    $exp = explode($replace, $str);

    $i = 1;
    $cnt = count($exp);
    $format_str = '';
    foreach($exp as $v)
    {
        if($i == 1)
        {
            $format_str = $v;
        }
        else if($i == $cnt)
        {
            $format_str .= $replaceWith . $v;
        }
        else
        {
            $format_str .= $replace . $v;
        }
        $i++;
    }
    return $format_str;
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately someone, who helped me with a conjugation script, didn't have time for some weeks or months, so I also searching for someone, who could helped me.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$str = 'accélérer';
$pos = strrpos( $str, 'é' );
if( $pos !== FALSE ) $str[$pos] = 'è';
```

Comment: @Andrew It should use the multi-byte safe strpos() operation `mb_strrpos` for this problem maybe. How to you echo this result?

Comment: It seems an encoding problem. Did you saved the file in UTF-8?

Comment: I substitute with `mb_strrpos( $str, 'é', "UTF-8" );` but the replacement still shows `�`...  :S , but if it works for you its fine

Comment: @Mat  Could you please add an output for my two examples?

Comment: Mmm, it works only if I save it in ANSI and then with `var_dump( utf8_encode( $str ) )` I get the correct values. Before: string(11) "accélérer" - after: string(11) "accélèrer" - There's something wrong with the encoding...

Comment: This is working in UTF-8, but it's a workaround, there is a better way for sure: `$str = 'accélérer';
$str2 = htmlentities( $str );
$pos = strrpos( $str2, '&eacute;' );
if( $pos !== FALSE ) var_dump( html_entity_decode( substr_replace( $str2, '&egrave;', $pos, strlen( '&egrave;' ) ) ) );`

Comment: Ah ok, you got the solution. I saw it now. Good :-)

Answer (score 0):

Mat's answer did not work on me, so I work on more and I found `è` is 2 btye in `strlen` and 1 byte in `mb_strlen`. So in order to work with `substr_replace`

```
$str = "accélérer";
$pos = mb_strrpos($str, "é", "UTF-8");
if ($pos !== false) {
    $str = substr_replace($str, "è", $pos + 1, strlen("è") );
}
var_dump($str); // string(11) "accélèrer"
```